# Why would file attachments not make it to an email enabled document library?

Tags: 2010, email-enabled-library

I have setup an email enabled document library in SharePoint 2010. It appears that most of the process is working.

**Use Case 1**

- In "Incoming E-mail Settings" I set "Save original e-mail?" to "Yes".
- I sent a test email with an attachment.
- I monitored the file that was dropped off in the mailroot drop folder and copied it to my desktop before SharePoint processed it.
- The .eml file shows up in the document library but it will not have an attachment.
- The .eml file I copy to my desktop does have an attachment.

**Use Case 2**

- In "Incoming E-mail Settings" I set "Save original e-mail?" to "No".
- I sent a test email with an attachment.
- The attachment never shows up in my document library.

It looks like somewhere between being dropped off in the mailroot drop and being processed by SharePoint the attachment is removed.

**Question**
Are there any settings that I can look at to debug this?

Comment: did you check this one https://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=32681

Comment: Which email client you are using to send email? What is the attachment file type and size?

Comment: It is a word document that is 30KB in size. I've sent messages from Outlook and gmail.